# Android ADB port number changes, Eclipse can't connect to devices

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, adb

I upgraded to a new pc using Windows 7.  Eclipse can't connect to the ADB.  Ever.  Task Manager shows the ADB port number to be anywhere from 3180 to 5452, never in the range 5555 to 5585 it should be at.  Going to the command prompt entering "kill-server" then "start-server" to reset last showed "daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * daemon started successfully" but the next command "adb devices" shows nothing attached.  The port number changes and DDMS shows the ADB was forcefully closed so there's a connection somewhere.

I tried updating drivers and forcing the port number connection using 'adb port xxxx' but obviously it hasn't worked or I wouldn't be posting here.  With my last pc using WinXP I was able to force the port number if needed to make it work but that isn't happening here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Update: I found HTC Sync has a driver with part of the package which now has the adb devices command showing a device and DDMS can see the phone attached via usb.  The ADB still won't work for debug purposes which seems odd if everything else can connect.  Apparently W7 doesn't include usb android drivers so the phone's OEM supplies them from their web sites and it's up to the user to install them.

Comment: Update 2: The phone needed to be assigned another drive letter because the one it was using was conflicting with a network drive.  This has not resolved the ADB issue but now the DDMS view in Eclipse can see the device.

Comment: Update 3: The final fix has been to uninstall Java 7 (jre7).  Java jre6 is still installed with the ADB now working normally.